# Kill unneeded timeouts?

Tags: jquery

Basically I made a kind of a luck spin game.

When you click on the button id "submit", it will do the following:

```
function loadLuck() {
    $("#luck").html('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/HSIICHd.gif" /> Please wait...');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $.post('ajax.php', {getLuck : '1'}, function(data) {
            $("#luck").html(data);
        });
    }, 1500);
}
```

basically loads result from a php page.

but if I click on it multiple times, it will generate new results , the same times as how much clicks i've done.

Thats because the timeouts are set.

How can I only enable 1 timeout per time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `clearTimeout` function:

```
var timeoutID = '';

function loadLuck() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    $("#luck").html('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/HSIICHd.gif" /> Please wait...');
    timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
        $.post('ajax.php', {getLuck : '1'}, function(data) {
            $("#luck").html(data);
        });
    }, 1500);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "debounce" function (such as [this one](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-debounce/)).

```
function loadLuck() {
  // ...
}
$('.loadLuck').click($.debounce(loadLuck, 1500));
```

Comment: .loadLuck is the class of the button that runs the code? if yes, it doesn't really work. Should it be inside a docmuent.ready?

Comment: how is "loadLuck" bound to your button?

Comment: <input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="loadLuck(); return false;">

Comment: bind your form them. `$('#myform').submit($.debounce(..` and reove that `onclick`.

Comment: did you remove the `onclick`? and yes, add a "return false"